# What is the purpose of this code? Is it just duplicating a Date?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I came across an ancient piece of code by someone who doesn't work in the company anymore.

I'm wondering what the purpose is of this calendar magic:

```
if (value instanceof Date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime((Date) value);
    return new Date(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

It seems to me this would return a new `Date` object with the same values as the original `value`. Is there some Calendar initialization going on that I'm missing?  If the purpose is to return a new object with the same value, I would assume `value.clone()` does the job:

```
(Date) originalDate.clone()
// or
new Date(originalDate.getTime())
```

Version control shows the code never changed. Are there possible side effects of pulling the date through a Calendar first?

Comment: It's not an exact copy since `Date` contains the time of day as well whereas the code above only considers year, month and day of month.

Comment: No, it won't result in an equal `Date` instance. It will be at midnight and the year will be less by 1900. It smells like very poor design.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The `-1900` part is actually because of `Date`'s weirdness. The code is correct on that part.

Comment: Don't assume that code you find on the web or elsewhere is logical - unfortunately, people often write something that seems to do what they want but they don't understand what they are writing themselves. This is especially true with Java `Date` and `Calendar`, which seems to be a confusing subject for many programmers.

Comment: I guess "ancient" is part of the answer, i.e. it might be from the time where that `Date` constructor wasn't deprecated (which would mean _really ancient_ :) ).

Comment: @Thomas to be fair, lots of people still use the constructor *even though* it's deprecated.

Comment: @Thomas If the purpose was to get rid of the timestamp, I would've expected `return new Date(oldDate.getYear(), ...)`.

Comment: Yeah I might expect the same. I can't tell why the code has been written that way (maybe the programmer was told to use that fancy new "Calendar" ;) ), I just can tell what it does.

Comment: @Kayaman clone can may cause some issues , you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java

Comment: @PavneetSingh you're basically right but `Date.clone()` won't just do a shallow copy if you have a look at the sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is nothing more than an **outdated way** to remove hours, minutes and seconds from your initial date.

As you can see in this simple example:

```
Date value = new Date();
System.out.printf("Before %s%n", value);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(value);
System.out.printf(
    "After %s%n", 
    new Date(
        calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900, 
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    )
);
```

**Output:**

```
Before Thu Oct 06 11:19:26 GMT 2016
After Thu Oct 06 00:00:00 GMT 2016
```

Comment: This is a way to remove the timestamp, yes, but if that was its purpose, it could be done with just Date rather than involve Calendar. `return new Date(oldDate.getYear(), ...)`. I'm wondering if the code is relying on side-effects of the Calendar.

Comment: I don't believe so, it just seem to be a misuse of `Calendar` and `Date`. You should not overthink it knowing that they are both *out dated* now with the arrival of the `java.time` package

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Filotto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39894585/642706) is correct, and should be accepted.

That code is trying to clear the time-of-day to `00:00:00`. But it is an abuse of the classes, ignores crucial issue of time zone, and uses the notoriously troublesome old date-time classes. Those old classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The programmer probably wanted either:

- Date-only value
- First moment of the day

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “America/Montreal” );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

> today.toString(): 2016-01-23

## `ZonedDateTime`

For a date-time value start by getting the current date as a `LocalDate` object as seen above. Then call [`atStartOfDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) to get the first moment of the day. Do *not* assume that first moment is the time `00:00:00`. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) means the first moment may be something like `01:00:00`. So let java.time determine that time-of-day.

```
ZonedDateTime todayStart = today.atStartOfDay( z );
```

> today.toString(): 2016-01-23T00:00:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

Tip: Never try to determine the *last* moment of the day. Always use the *first* moment of the *following* day. Search Stack Overflow for "Half-Open" for more info.

## `Instant`

Much of your work should be done in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). To move your `ZonedDateTime` into UTC, extract an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = zdtStart.toInstant();
```

## Conversion

You should avoid the legacy date-time classes. But if you must interoperate with some old code not yet updated to the java.time types, you can convert to/from java.time. Look for new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( zdtStart );
java.util.Date d = Date.from( instant );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).